# Golang worker using wait groups

Tags: go, concurrency, worker

I'm new to Golang and trying to understand how WaitGroups and concurrency in Golang works. In this example, 5 workers are created with a channel for passing a job to each worker. The workers are made to sleep for 1 second to simulate a heavy computation. All goes well, but the program does not quit gracefully. Instead this error message is printed. Please help understand why this happens.

`fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

This is the code,

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, messageChannel <-chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range messageChannel {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("done processing - ", i)
    }
}

func stop(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    fmt.Println("waiting on the main thread")
    wg.Wait()
}

func main() {
    wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)
    messageChannel := make(chan string, 50)

    // create workers
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(wg, messageChannel)
    }

    // input some messages
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        messageChannel <- fmt.Sprint(i)
    }

    stop(wg)
    close(messageChannel)
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The workers can't exit until the channel is closed (because `for range` works this way), and the channel isn't closed until the workers are done. Swap the stop and close calls at the end of main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand a bit on @Peter's comment, here is the execution flow of the code that you wrote:

- After initialization, you start your `worker` goroutines. Each `worker` goroutine will range over `messageChannel`, with a time delay of 1 second will print out a message.
- Next, you insert some message in `messageChannel` through a for-loop. Each available `worker` goroutine receives a message until all messages are processed and printed out. After that, the `worker` goroutines are waiting for new messages to come from the `messageChannel`.
- After your for-loop for inserting messages in the `messageChannel` is completed, you execute the `stop` function, which blocks on `wg.Wait()` and waits for all `wg.Done()` calls to be executed in all `worker` goroutines. However, since `messageChannel` is not closed, none of the `worker` goroutines can finish execution and none of the `wg.Done()` calls are executed.
- The `worker` goroutines are stuck because the `messageChannel` never closes, the `main` goroutine is stuck because of the `wg.Wait()` call inside the `stop` function, and you end up with a deadlock where all goroutines are asleep.

Per suggestion, you just need to swap places for `stop` and `close` calls

```
//rest of the code
close(messageChannel)
stop(wg)
```

This way, when all messages are inserted in the `messageChannel`, you call `close(messageChannel)` and then `stop(wg)`, which blocks on the `wg.Wait` call. The `close(messageChannel)` call ensures that, once all messages are read from the `messageChannel`, `for-range` loops on the `messageChannel` inside the `worker` goroutines will exit, and all `defer wg.Done()` calls will be executed. Once this happens, `wg.Wait()` will unblock and the program will finish execution properly.